# Getting errors trying to add an event to Android calendar

Tags: android

I'm getting problems creating a new Calendar event from my Android app. Here's my code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, dtStart.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(0)).toEpochMilli());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, dtEnd.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(0)).toEpochMilli());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, edittext.getText().toString());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calId);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.VISIBLE, 0);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
}
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
```

I'm getting the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only the provider may write to visible

I've had a good look around but can't find anything I'm doing wrong, all the code examples I've seen are basically the same as the above. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the visibility of an event via a ContentResolver. Comment out the line

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.VISIBLE, 0);
```

and try again.

Building up from this Android documentation

[Writing to Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events#writing-to-events)